# Relational algebra - Functional Dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

I just want to be sure... If i've two dependencies like

- a -> c
- b -> c

Will it be the same as this one

- a b -> c

Comment: What reference are you using? What is the *definition* of "FD"? What have you tried? Why do you suspect yes, and why no? What happens when you try numerous small examples (in case that disproves one choice)? What has your googling told you? Please read [ask].

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "if... the same as" or what the "it" is that the 3rd FD would be "the same as". Look at what happens if we replace the FDs by other statements: If x=1 will it be the same as x>0? Do you mean, Are the *statements* "the same", or If x=1 then is x>0? Please use technical terms and clear sentences. Do you mean, is the pair holding the same as the 3rd holding? Or, if those 1st two hold, does that 3rd also hold? Ie, if the truth value of the conjunction of the 1st two is TRUE, will that truth value be the same as the truth value of the 3rd? ("if"+""the same as"=ugly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you are asking if the two sets of functional dependencies `{a → c, b → c}` and `{ab → c}` are equivalent. The answer to this question is *no*.

From either `a → c` or `b → c` you *can* prove `ab → c` (by applying the definition of functional dependency: `x → y` if and only if, when two tuples have the same values for `x`, they have also the same values for `y`). You can also derive `ab → c` with the [Armstrong’s Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) (e.g. starting from `a → c` and applying first the augmentation axiom with `b`, obtaining `ab → bc`, then applying the decomposition to obtain `ab → c`).

But the viceversa is not true: you cannot prove from `ab → c` that `a → c`, neither that `b → c`, and equivalently you cannot derive any of the two dependencies from `ab → c` through the Armstrong’s Axioms. For an example, consider the dependency `StudentNumber, CourseName → Grade` (that asserts that there can be only a `Grade` from a certain couple `StudentNumber` and `CourseName`). From this dependency you cannot assert that for a `StudentNumber` there is only a `Grade`, or for a `CourseName` there is only a `Grade`.